# Download files from web api hosted on azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

We have implemented file download functionality and which was working fine from last 3-4 months, but suddenly we are not able to download the file from yesterday. Also, there is no code changes and no other code is affecting the functionality.

Our web api & UI is hosted on azure cloud.

This is occurring in all environments dev, qa etc.

So is there any restriction on azure web app for downloading the files ?

Also, our UI is on angular 6 where they download the file from the response sent from the api.

Below is our sample code

```
public IActionResult DownloadFile(int ID)
{
    try
    {
        if (ValidateUsrToken())
        {
            using (ExcelPackage package = BAL.DownloadFile(ID))
            {
                string fileName = Uri.EscapeDataString(package.File.Name);

                System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                {
                    FileName = fileName,
                };

                Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

                return File(package.GetAsByteArray(), "application /vndopenxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            }
        }
        else throw new NullReferenceException();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

We are using epplus library to create file in excel format.

Comment: Have you turned on logging? Asp net core logging is very thorough.

Comment: If you access the web api directly from web browser, will it download this file? Try to return the existing file to see whether it is related with `ExcelPackage`. Do you receive any error?